# Another integral of result $\ln {3}$

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

> $$\int_{0}^{1}(-1-x^2+x^4+x^6)\cdot{\mathrm dx\over (1+x^2)^2\ln{x}}=\ln{3}\tag1$$
>
> How can we show that $(1)=\ln{3}?$

$${-1-x^2+x^4+x^6\over (1+x^2)^2}$$changing this into a partial fraction...

I am not sure...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Observe that $\;x^6+x^4-x^2-1=(x^2+1)(x^4-1)=(x^2+1)^2(x^2-1)\;$

so your integral actually is

$$\int_0^1\frac{x^2-1}{\log x}dx$$

Now put

$$I(a):=\int_0^1\frac{x^{2a}-1}{\log x}dx\implies I'(a)=\int_0^1\frac{2x^{2a}\log x}{\log x}dx=\left.\frac2{2a+1}x^{2a+1}\right|_0^1=\frac2{2a+1}\implies$$

$$I(a)=\int\frac2{2a+1}da=\log(2a+1)$$

and now just put $\;a=1\;$ and we're done.

Comment: Don't you need to evaluate $I$ at some value $a>-\frac{1}{2}$ as well?

Comment: @CarlSchildkraut That is implicitly understood. You may as well write instead $\;\log|2a+1|\;,\;\;a\neq-\frac12\;$ ....and observe I also didn't write the integration constant: I don't need to. In fact, if the OP is interested he can justify all this and/or read about Feynman's Trick

Comment: @DonAntonio Wh didn't you need the +C?

Comment: @Botond Because I can choose it as I like. In fact, instead of antidifferentiating in the last step I can integrate between zero and $\;1\;$ and get the exact result.

Comment: @DonAntonio I think you can't choose it as you like. But integrating from $0$ to $1$ do really solve the constant-problem.

Answer (score 1):

Clearly $x^6+x^4-x^2-1=(x^2+1)^2(x^2-1)$, so remains
$$I=\int_0^1\dfrac{x^2-1}{\ln x}dx$$
One way is solving it with Laplace transform, then with $x=e^t$
$$I=\int_0^\infty\dfrac{1-e^{2t}}{t}e^t\,dt=\int_0^\infty\dfrac{e^t-e^{3t}}{t}dt=\int_0^\infty\dfrac{1}{s-1}-\dfrac{1}{s-3}ds=\ln\dfrac{s-1}{s-3}\Big|_0^\infty=\color{blue}{\ln3}$$

Answer (score 1):

Your integral can also be reduced to a [Frullani Integral](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/FrullanisIntegral.html) as follows. Since
$$I = \int^1_0 \frac{x^2 - 1}{\ln x} \, dx,$$
if we let $x \mapsto e^{-x}$ then
$$I = \int^\infty_0 \frac{e^{-x} - e^{-3x}}{x} \, dx.$$

Now as the above integral for $I$ is of the form of a Frullani integral, namely
$$\int^\infty_0 \frac{f(ax) - f(bx)}{x} \, dx = (f(0) - f(\infty)) \ln \left (\frac{b}{a} \right ),$$
where $f(x) = e^{-x}, a = 1, b = 3$, as $f(0) = \lim_{x \to 0^+} f(x) = 1$ and $f(\infty) = \lim_{x \to \infty} f(x) = 0$ we have
$$\int^1_0 \frac{x^6 + x^4 - x^2 - 1}{(1 + x^2)^2 \ln x} \, dx = \ln (3),$$
as required.

Answer (score 0):

**hint**

$$-1-x^2+x^4+x^6=(1+x^2)(x^4-1) $$
$$=(1+x^2)^2 (x^2-1) $$